# pycharm and unittesting - structuring project

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I am using pycharm at one of my university projects and I wanted to integrated it with `unittest` module, but I have a problem with structuring my project

Part of this project involves  generating abstract syntax trees, so I created `AST` directory and put `__init__.py` there, then I created `expression` module. I wanted to put my tests in `test/` subdirectory, so it would look like this:

```
AST/
  __init__.py
  expression.py
  test/
      some_test.py
  utils.py
```

now I have also module in my `AST` called `symbol_table` and module called `utils`, example test class looks like

```
import unittest
from ...AST import expression
from ...AST import utils


class ConstantExpressionTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def testConstantExpressionCheck(self):
        constantExpression = expression.ConstantExpression(17, 5, utils.TYPES.INT)
        self.assertTrue(constantExpression.check())
```

when I right click on this file and select `Run Unittest in ...` I am getting errors:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/xubuntu/Downloads/pycharm-2.7.2/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /home/xubuntu/Przedmioty/VI/kompilatory/tk-projekt/src/AST/test/test_constant_expression.py true
Testing started at 12:06 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xubuntu/Downloads/pycharm-2.7.2/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 110, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "/home/xubuntu/Downloads/pycharm-2.7.2/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 34, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/home/xubuntu/Przedmioty/VI/kompilatory/tk-projekt/src/AST/test/test_constant_expression.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ...AST import utils
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have read about this problem and if I understand this right, this file is treated as it would be in top-level package so I can't use any relative imports.

But if that is the case, how can I run unit-tests from pycharm and also keep my current project strcture?

If I am not mistaken, putting tests in sub-package is pretty popular (http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) so there must be some kind of solution

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is a bit silly, I found out that pycharm adds the root of the project to path so I can just use normal imports from the root of my project.

So for example I can write

`from AST import expression` in my `some_test` file