# Pycharm Unit Testing without restructuring

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm

I've been using PyCharm to develop a submodule to drop into several other projects. I have a Tests directory containing my unit tests and I'd like to run them from PyCharm, but when I test any of my code that contains relative imports, I get:

"ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

My structure is roughly:

A
    ____init____.py
    ...
B
    ____init____.py
    ...
Tests
    ____init____.py
    ...

Where I am testing a function in the B module that uses relative imports to import A:

`from ..A import some_fn`

This thread here [pycharm and unittesting - structuring project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613501/pycharm-and-unittesting-structuring-project) references marking the test directory as such, but when I right click it, I only have the option to mark it as a source root which has no effect.

I also can't really change from relative to absolute imports because it will break my ability to use it as a submodule in other projects. Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

**Update**: I also came across this thread [How to properly use relative or absolute imports in Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616952/how-to-properly-use-relative-or-absolute-imports-in-python-modules) and I'm not a huge fan of the solution (I'd prefer not to have mirror imports in a try/except block), but it does somewhat solve the problem. I would still appreciate a more elegant solution, but if not, that does actually fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `A` and `B` are different packages. You want them both to be subpackages of the the `myproj` package.

I think all you are missing is a `__init__.py` file in the parent directory. Allowing you to relatively import something in `B` from something in `A`

```
myproj/
├── A
│   └── __init__.py
├── B
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```